# Query to update table comparing to other table and delete if not there

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'am struggling to do a query in Postgres, let me explain:

I want to update table **users** with the fresh new users I got in other table called **users_temp**. This **users_temp** contains the latest users from my Telegram channel. The difficult part: I want that if there is a new user in the **users_temp** table, it gets added into my **users** table, and if I get any user that is in **users** table but is not inside **users_temp**, I want delete it from **users**. BTW to identify user, Its a simple 'userId' column.

Is it possible to do it in a single query? I tryied MERGE, UNIONS but just can't find a way out using only one single query. Also, I kind of need the query to be relatively fast, because of the big number of lines.

Thanks

Comment: do you have to go with one query? why not insert followed by delete or vice versa?

Comment: The way you describe it, it sounds like you want to replace the old table with the new one. Can you describe the difference?

Comment: some colums of users table cant be lost. Only because of that it cant be done Laurenz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can INSERT and UPDATE in a single query, but it is *not possible* to INSERT and DELETE in a single query.

What you can do is INSERT and DELETE in a single **transaction**:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO nu
      SELECT nu.*
      FROM new_users nu
      LEFT JOIN Users u ON u.UserId=nu.UserId
      WHERE u.UserId IS NULL;

    DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM new_users);

COMMIT
```

And if you are trying to issue this command from a client application, it's usually perfectly okay to issue that one long string as a single command to the database.

The other alternative is to do a *soft delete*, where you simply use the UPDATE side of a MERGE query to mark the record as deleted. This might allow to you write a **trigger** which would then delete the record.

Answer (score 0):

Marging can be done in single query, but you have prepare transfer table first.

Create copy of `users` table:

```
create table users_copy as select * from users;
```

Delete all rows from `users`

```
truncate users;
```

And finally:

```
insert into users select users_temp.* from users_temp LEFT OUTER JOIN copy_of_users on users_temp.userId=copy_of_users.users_temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

solved with two queries:

```
delete from users as u where not exists (select 1 from users_temp where u.userId = users_temp.userId)

insert into users (userId,username) select t.userId,t.username from users_temp t on conflict (userId) do nothing
```

Thanks for your help!